# Pointer to member that is a reference illegal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

Let us say I have:

```
// This is all valid in C++11.
struct Foo {
    int i = 42;
    int& j = i;
};

// Let's take a pointer to the member "j".
auto b = &Foo::j; // Compiler is not happy here
// Note that if I tried to get a pointer to member "i", it would work, as expected.
Foo f;
std::cout << f.*b; // Try using the pointer to member
```

The compiler complains that I cannot take the address of the member because it is a reference. To be precise:

> Semantic Issue: Cannot form a pointer-to-member to member 'j' of reference type 'int &'

I know doing this seems pointless, but I am only wondering why it cannot be done.

Why is this impossible?

Comment: @SethCarnegie : I meant Foo, sorry. :)

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav b is a pointer to member, not a member. Noticed the .*?

Comment: @Doug: That's what the question's about.  *Why* isn't this valid C++?

Comment: You could always use a reference wrapper. You can create pointers to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Member pointer (as opposed to a simple pointer to a member) is simply an offset into the structure, not a pointer at all. You can get data through it only in conjunction with the structure itself (or a pointer to a structure): the value of the offset is added to the address of the structure, and the result is dereferenced to produce the value of the member.

Now suppose a member is a reference, so accessing data through it already requires a dereference (compiler hides it from us, but it needs to spit out the corresponding instructions in its output). If C++ were to allow member pointers to references, they'd be of yet another type: an offset that needs to be added to the base, and then dereferenced twice. It is too much work to improve an already obscure feature; prohibiting it is a much better way out.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Well, that's pointers to member functions. Pointers to data members are much less sophisticated, because data members cannot be virtual.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer I've gotten so far. It explains WHY the feature is not supported. So I'm not crazy of expecting it to work. It only means that it's not supported.

Comment: @fronsacqc Sure, this feature can be made to work if you shoehorn it into some meaningful semantic. Unfortunately, doing so for an obscure feature like this belongs to the domain of problems, not solutions. Fortunately, someone on the standardization committee has recognized it early on, and banned the feature before it became a problem.

Answer (score 14):

It cannot be done because you cannot take a pointer to a reference- period.

If you could take a member pointer to a reference, this would be inconsistent with the behaviour of references on the stack. The attitude of C++ is that references do not exist. As such, you cannot form a pointer to them- ever.

For example, `&f::a` would have to be different to `&f::b`. And by de-referencing `&f::b`, you would effectively be achieving a pointer to a reference, which is not allowed.

Comment: +1. The first statement is *indeed* the precise answer. References to pointers are allowed but pointers to references are not.

Comment: @DeadMG : What do you mean by the "behavior of references on the stack?"

Comment: But I do `&my_vector[0]` all the time - and I'm sure `operator[]` returns a reference.

Comment: @fronsacqc: If you took a pointer to `int&` that was on the stack, you'd get an `int*`. However, by obtaining a pointer-to-member-reference, you are effectively circumventing that and achieving a pointer to reference. `&f::a` would have to be different to `&f::b`, which is not allowed, since references are not objects.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That does not yield a pointer to a reference, it yields a pointer to the object which was referred to. Different things.

Comment: Then I think your first statement is too strong - you *can* take a pointer to a reference, but it doesn't provide a pointer to the reference itself but to the referred object.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You can take the *address of* a reference, which is the address of the reference's object. You can not point to a reference itself.

Answer (score 14):

C++11 standard:

> §8.3.3 p3 [dcl.mptr]
> A pointer to member shall not point to a static member of a class (9.4), **a member with reference type**, or “cv void.”

Also, in general:

> §8.3.1 p4 [dcl.ptr]
> [ Note: There are no pointers to references; see 8.3.2. [...] —end note ]
>
> §8.3.2 p5 [dcl.ref]
> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and **no pointers to references**.

Comment: I'm asking WHY is the standard against it. I'd love to the reason.

Comment: @fronsacqc: Well, then you'll have to mail the standard committee's mailing list `comp.lang.c++.moderated` or hope for Howard Hinnant (a member of the committee roaming around SO) to answer this question.

Comment: @fronsacqc: Because pointers point to objects, but references aren't objects.

Comment: @Fred: Good point, when I get back from work I'll edit this answer to include that supported by standard quotes. Atleast that should be doable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Allowing you to make a pointer to a reference does not give you any expressive power. There's nothing you can do with such a beast that you can't easily do with a reference or with a pointer. All you get out of it is added complexity.

And making a pointer to a member that is a reference is not allowed for consistency with the rule that forbids pointers to references, and because it adds even more complexity. The designers of the language probably decided that the little gains you get from these was not worth it.

This is totally just my opinion.

Comment: You can't simultaneously claim that it gives you **no** expressive power, yet claim pointers to reference member have "**little** gains". If B is useful and A allows B, then A must in some ways also be useful.