# Type trait: Check if reference member variable is static or not

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, type-traits

I would like to check if a member variable of a class is static or not. Using *std::is_member_pointer* works fine for all types except for reference members.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
  int foo;
};

struct B : A {};

struct C {
  static int foo;
};

struct D : C {
};

struct E {
  int &foo;
};

struct F {
  static int &foo;
};

static_assert(std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&A::foo)>::value, "No");
static_assert(std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&B::foo)>::value, "No");
static_assert(!std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&C::foo)>::value, "No");
static_assert(!std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&D::foo)>::value, "No");

// Fail to compile:
static_assert(std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&E::foo)>::value, "No");

static_assert(!std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&F::foo)>::value, "No");
```

[Live example.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4AuBPADgg%2BmgJwEMQ0BnAPgCgqzCYI0kBBJAbyqSXCYDMB7fgG4qAXxG16jJACEkALhbtxNOgQZMAwu05I6RNCAjcwfQSJWT10gCIKk2jpbUakAUR1ceSAGQDhYhIu0gBinnpoBkYmTH7mgaqRhhC4RGRkCARoABR0cPLyIGS4ALYIJQBGmbhY/DyZKIjQmDjZPswF/gCUFAUAbkSwCAA0SABEAHL8Y10i%2Bsmp6Zk5eQVFpeVVBDV1pg1NUC0IbTKdgj39gzAj41Mzc0lGixlZ2QCEq4XFZZXVtfUERoIZrYY4%2BTRnfgXeQDIajSbTWaSKIpNIvHIfND5L4bX7bf57QEHI5tGyQ6Gw67wu5IqgAejpSBCJCgSDQ/CQEH4JSwICgCHkyIWaOWuSxa2%2Bmz%2BuzQ%2B2Bh1BbTc5N6MKuNwR9yFTxFr0x2PWPy2OwBQJBrR8IRVlzht0REiAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

I understand the error, that a pointer cannot point to a reference member. But how to avoid it and still distinguish if it is a static or non static variable? Any idea on that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336274/pointer-to-member-that-is-a-reference-illegal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a fallback in case `&E::foo` fails using SFINAE (and another one in case `E::foo` does not exist at all):

```
template <typename T>
std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&T::foo)> is_member_foo(int);

template <typename T>
decltype(T::foo, std::true_type{}) is_member_foo(long);

template <typename T>
std::false_type is_member_foo(...);

template <typename T>
using IsMemberFoo = decltype(is_member_foo<T>(0));

static_assert(IsMemberFoo<A>{}, "No");
static_assert(IsMemberFoo<B>{}, "No");
static_assert(!IsMemberFoo<C>{}, "No");
static_assert(!IsMemberFoo<D>{}, "No");
static_assert(IsMemberFoo<E>{}, "No");
static_assert(!IsMemberFoo<F>{}, "No");
static_assert(!IsMemberFoo<G>{}, "No"); // struct G { };
```

What this code does:

- If `&T::foo` is valid, it will check if the member is static or not using `std::is_member_pointer` (your version).
- If `&T::foo` is not valid, it falls back to the second overload (here you are sure that `foo` is not static, or the first overload would have been chosen):

  - If `T::foo` is valid (a member exists), it returns `std::true_type`.
  - Otherwize it falls back to the last overload and returns `std::false_type`.

Also note (thanks to @iammilind) that for `private` member, `T::foo` is *not valid*, so the third overload will be chosen.

Working example on ideone: http://ideone.com/FILHbK

Side notes (extended explanation):

- When `&T::foo` is valid, the two first overloads are valid, but the first one is chosen since `int` is an exact match while `long` is not.
- `decltype(T::foo, std::true_type{})`: `T::foo` is only here to "let SFINAE" fall back to the third overload if `T::foo` is not valid, but the resulting type is `std::true_type` thanks to the comma operator.

If you like, you can also create a *generic* version (http://ideone.com/lzH2FB):

```
#define IsMember(MEM) \
template <typename T> \
std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&T::MEM)> is_member_##MEM(int); \
template<typename T> \
decltype(T::MEM, std::true_type{}) is_member_##MEM(long); \
template <typename T> \
std::false_type is_member_##MEM(...); \
template <typename T> \
using IsMember_##MEM = decltype(is_member_##MEM<T>(0));

// Instanciate IsMember_foo
IsMember(foo);

// Use it:
static_assert(IsMember_foo<A>{}, "No");
```

Also see these two answers if you want to encapsulate everything in a class (without having `is_member_` functions):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36694627/2666289
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693801/2666289

Comment: Your answer seems correct to me. Upvoted it. Can you make some changes in the example code? 1. `C` is repeating twice, but `D` is not there. 2. Replace `typename C` with `typename T` as it creates confusion for readers (there is already a `class C`). Both in the example code and your answer. BTW, your SFINAE understanding is quite good and instead of creating the stand-alone codes like above, you should create a library like code using macro. Also put a note that, it may not work for `private` variables.

Comment: @iammilind Thanks, I have updated the answer and the ideone code.

Comment: Your new way of creating generic member is good. But just imagine that, it will end up creating lots of `is_member_##MEM` due to its exclusivity. Hence you should think of a way, where you can encapsulate in a class and keep utilizing the same one. Technically there is nothing wrong, even if you create so many of such templates. But, there is simply no need to do so. The side advantage of `class` is that, you can have a `bool value`, which can be used for printing/checking purpose as well.

Comment: @iammilind Actually, `IsMember_foo` is a class which can be converted to `bool`, it will either be `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant), and then you can convert it to bool, instanciate it, access `::value`, and so on. I hesitated to do as you say by encapsulating everything in a class, but then I would not be able to have the "benefits" of `std::integral_constant` (I don't think there is a performance issue with this way, except may name collision, because the functions does not have body so they won't have any impact).

Comment: @iammilind I have added link to both your and my answer in the related topic if someone wants to encapsulate everything in a class because this answer is already pretty long.